# Python json.loads shows ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1

Tags: json, delimiter

I'm trying to read a json file of tweets but i keep getting this error

ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 537 (char 536)

```
Code:
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import json

with open('/Users/Mustafa/desktop/tweets.json', 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline() # read only the first tweet/line
    tweet = json.loads(line) # load it as Python dict
    print(json.dumps(tweet, indent=4)) # pretty-print
```

any idea how I can fix this or what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

BAD json file without delimiter in it it`s not json! put the delimiter in file!!!

sublime text will show you line and row
cntr+p  :linenumber:columnumber